# Google finds text that is not in the question / answer

Tags: discussion

I ran into a strange problem. I wanted to find information about using a regular expression to extract any cell reference from an Excel formula, so I googled

> vba regex extract address from formula

The top hit gave me the following "teaser text" which showed me I was on the right track:
[image]

I was intrigued by the line

> Is this the RegEx for matching any cell reference in an Excel formula?

So I clicked through to [the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146485/returning-a-regex-match-in-vba-excel)

When I got there I could **not** find the text that Google returned. Is it seeing things that have been deleted? What's going on here?

As always, I eagerly await your pearls of wisdom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears in the "Related Questions" sidebar:

> [image]

Google can't know (well, it can, but it's not yet smart enough) it's not part of the actual question.

Comment: #Facepalm#! I never look at the "advertising" on the right, and it had not occurred to me that these links would become the thing that led Google to this page. Apparently the question I found has a higher Google rank than the question I apparently wanted. Anyway - I appreciate your help in clearing this up for me!

Comment: No problem @Floris that's what we're here for. :-)